# wx.RichTextCtrl - How to remove blinking cursor from rich text ctrl box?

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm using C++. A simple rich text ctrl box with some sentences. I'm using this because I require the scroll. My problem is the blinking cursor at the start of the text (As shown in the image below)

[image: wxwidgets]

I searched the internet and found this piece of code:

http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?p=96307

In the above link I found info for the text ctrl it goes something like this:

```
textctrl->SetFocus();
textctrl->ShowNativeCaret(false);
```

But I did not find valuable information for the RichTextCtrl box

Also I tried to set the cursor as a blank cursor but it did not work for me

```
window->SetCursor(wxCursor(wxCURSOR_WAIT));
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`wxTextCtrl::ShowNativeCaret()` is implemented only on Windows and simply uses native APIs [`ShowCaret()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648406.aspx) and [`HideCaret()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648403.aspx).

You can easily replicate this for `wxRichTextCtrl` by hooking the set focus event:

```
richTextCtrl->Bind(wxEVT_SET_FOCUS, [richTextCtrl](wxFocusEvent&) {
    HideCaret(richTextCtrl->GetHWND());
});
```

(Or using member function instead if your compiler does not support C++11 lambdas yet. See "Dynamic Event Handling" chapter [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html) for more information.)